# Separar lineas de un campo TEXT en MYSQL mediante comas

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla con una columna TEXTO que no siempre tiene la misma cantidad de items (estos items los separo por una coma).  Lo que quiero hacer, si se puede, es alguna sentencia para que me separe cada item en una fila despues de la coma para mostrar mediante PHP en documento html. [image: esta es la tabla]
[[image: Asi se muestra actulamente][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lac7g.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurren un par de formas, desde *PHP*, para conseguir eso una vez ya tienes ese campo en una variable, que vamos a denominar **$detalles** en estos ejemplos:

1. Con funciones de reemplazo de caracteres como [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) (también hay otras directas como [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace))

```php
$detalles_en_lineas_para_textarea = str_replace(",", "\r\n", $detalles);
$detalles_en_lineas_para_html = str_replace(",", "<br />", $detalles);
```

2. Con [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode) y [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode):

```php
$detalles_en_lineas_para_textarea = implode("\r\n", explode(",",$detalles));
$detalles_en_lineas_para_html = implode("<br />", explode(",",$detalles));
```

En las variables **$detalles_en_lineas_para_textarea** las lineas seran separadas mediante retornos de carro, expresados con `"\r\n"` y en un **textarea** deberian mostrarse bien.

En las variables **$detalles_en_lineas_para_html** las lineas seran separadas en HTML mediante el elemento [`<br />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) que produce el mismo efecto, pero para contenido HTML (en los *textarea* raramente se usa HTML para su contenido).

Si te encuentras con texto que ya tiene líneas partidas puedes usar [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) para convertir los saltos de linea a `<br />` en HTML.

Answer (score 0):

con estas linea en mi recorrido de iteracion logre hacer lo que neceistaba

```
`$it_det = str_replace(",", "<br />", $row['items']);`
```

`<td style="width:60%"><?= $it_det; ?></td>`

este es el resultado:

[image: cada item separado en una fila]